# c++ Looking for a sane way to work with SqlServer data type datetime

Tags: c++, sql-server, datetime

The SqlServer datetime data type is used to hold timestamps and it is 64 bits long - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

I am looking for a sane way to work with it in C++, something in the boost library, probably?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I would settle for being able to do these two operations:

- Display the timestamp in some human readable format, like `2012-01-15 16:54:13.123`
- Parse a string like `2012-01-15 16:54:13.123` into the respective SqlServer datetime value.

**EDIT2**

Here is what I know until now. I have a table with a `datetime` column. When I select rows from it, I get this column back with the data type of `DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP`. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx it should be an 8 byte value, however, I get back a 16 byte value, for instance:

```
00070015000c07db 00000000001f0007
```

I could not find any description of this format, but examining it reveals the following structure:

```
0007 0015 000c 07db 00000000 001f 0007
 ^    ^    ^    ^             ^    ^
 |    |    |    |             |    |
 |    |    |    |             |    +--- minutes (7)
 |    |    |    |             +----+--- seconds (31)
 |    |    |    +-------------+----+--- year    (2011)
 |    |    +----+-------------+----+--- month   (12)
 |    +----+----+-------------+----+--- day     (21)
 +----+----+----+-------------+----+--- hour    (7)
```

Which corresponds to `2011-12-21 07:07:31`. So, this appears to be easy, but where is the documentation? Are `DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP` values always reported in this format? Is it SqlSever CE specific or whether the Express and other flavours work the same? Can it contain milliseconds?

BTW, I am using OLEDB to access the database.

Comment: There's no such thing as " sane way " when using C++, that's why we all love it :) ?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677303.aspx MS SqlServer does not have a `TimeStamp` data type. There is the OLEDB designation `DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP` which corresponds to the `datetime` family of SqlServer data types.

Comment: My bad. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28SQL.80%29.aspx it does have a timestamp type. However, as far as I understand, DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP is not a data type, but a date _formatting_ type. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677303.aspx

Comment: How do I arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you handle the thing on the side of the sql-server?

You could write a view, which gives you the DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP as datetime or varchar back. You could just define, which format you want.

```
Use the cast()- or convert()- Function
```

To write back values, you could wirte a little function, also at the sql-server.
You could use the function:

```
Convert(datetime, [value], [format])
```

Comment: I only have a read-only access to the database, so I cannot create any views.

Comment: You could do that also in a select-statement!